# Unset regions for specific content type

Tags: 7, theming

I want to create a special content type that doesn't include the logo and main navigation. I have a helper module and have added the following section before renenabling it but it doesn't seem to be having an affect. What might I be doing wrong?

```
function myhelpermodule_page_alter(&$page) {
  if (current_path() == 'node/add/specialcontenttype') {
    unset($page['header']);
  }
}
```

Just in case I got "header" wrong, I've tried it with 'footer' and other regions to test it out and it seems to be having no affect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hook suggestion in page preprocess and theme that page

for eg:

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Now clear the caches 
Duplicate page.tpl.php and rename it as page--specialcontenttype.tpl.php

Then, remove the `<?php print render($page['header']); ?>` etc.. from it

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to achieve this is to have a custom page.tpl.php file for your particular content type. That way you can remove the regions you don't need from the specific template file.

It's easily done with a few lines of code in your theme's template.php file and creating a new page template file. You'll find lots of tutorials online.

Here's one to get you started: https://www.digett.com/insights/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7